# arraylist containts duplicate values with Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

A very strange situation I noticed…

```
  private void saveFavArticles() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PUT_FAVORITE_CRNT_ARTICLE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String currentFavList = pref.getString(PUT_FAVORITE_CRNT_ARTICLE_KEY, "");
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    //if we have favorite articles
    if(currentFavList != "") {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Article>>(){}.getType();
        articles = new Gson().fromJson(currentFavList, type);
        //It returns true if the specified element is found in the list else it gives false.
        if(articles.contains(currentArticle))
            Toast.makeText(this, "this article exists into favorite list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else{
            articles.add(currentArticle);
            Toast.makeText(this, "current article added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(DetailsActivity.PUT_FAVORITE_CRNT_ARTICLE_KEY, new Gson().toJson(articles));
    }else {
        editor = pref.edit();
        articles.add(currentArticle);
        editor.putString(DetailsActivity.PUT_FAVORITE_CRNT_ARTICLE_KEY, new Gson().toJson(articles));
        Toast.makeText(this, "current article added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

I am debugging this statement… the problem is that even when my arraylist contains currentArticle it always said is not.

any help?

Comment: Does it always satisfy else condition?

Comment: yes. the problem is in line: if(articles.contains(currentArticle)). it always return false. if I change to: if(!articles.contains(currentArticle)) so it doing: Toast.makeText(this, "this article exists into favorite list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As articles arraylist is list of custom objects you need to override equals method assuming that the default implementation is not what you need.

> The List.contains(...) method is defined to use equals(Object) to
>   decide if the argument object is "contained" by the list.
>   when you compare objects(with contains method), it actually compares the hashcode generated by JAVA.

so your model class must override **equals** and **hashCode** methods

```
  @Override
public boolean equals(final Object object) {

    if (object instanceof Selector) {

        Selector target = (Selector) object;

        return target.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name);

    }

    return false;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return toString().hashCode();
}
```

my sample model class is

```
public final class Selector {

    private String name;

    public Selector(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object object) {

        if (object instanceof Selector) {

            Selector target = (Selector) object;

            return target.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name);

        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return toString().hashCode();
    }

}
```

here I am comparing my objects based on **NAME** , In your case you can use your variables.

Comment: thank you very much!! I spent a lot of time because that and you currently save my life

Answer (score 0):

Your shared preference identifier key and put text identifier key was same that's why it occurred problem. I just changed put string identifier key. Now it's working. Hope it will work for you as well

```
private String FAV_LIST = "fav_list";

private void saveFavArticles() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PUT_FAVORITE_CRNT_ARTICLE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String currentFavList = pref.getString(FAV_LIST, "");
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    //if we have favorite articles
    if (currentFavList != "") {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Article>>() {
        }.getType();
        articles = new Gson().fromJson(currentFavList, type);
        //It returns true if the specified element is found in the list else it gives false.
        if (articles.contains(currentArticle))
            Toast.makeText(this, "this article exists into favorite list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            articles.add(currentArticle);
            Toast.makeText(this, "current article added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(FAV_LIST, new Gson().toJson(articles));
    } else {
        editor = pref.edit();
        articles.add(currentArticle);
        editor.putString(FAV_LIST, new Gson().toJson(articles));
        Toast.makeText(this, "current article added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    editor.commit();
   }   
 }
```